# Sqlserver connection failed from jasperserver running on docker container?

Tags: java, windows, docker, azure-sql-database, jasperserver

I'm running jasperserver-pro(trail version) on docker container which runs fine. I have a sqlserver on azure cloud. When I try to create a connection from jasperserver running on docker container to sqlserver i'm not able to connect.

I download mysql jdbc  drivers and uploaded to jasperserver too. Below is the error.

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to buyeatest2sqldwserver.database.windows.net:1433: Connection reset at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:123) at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:69) at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:110) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(JdbcDriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:36) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDataSourceService.testConnection(JdbcDataSourceService.java:85) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.connection.JdbcConnectionStrategy.createConnection(JdbcConnectionStrategy.java:75) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.connection.JdbcConnectionStrategy.createConnection(JdbcConnectionStrategy.java:55) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.connection.ConnectionsManager.createConnection(ConnectionsManager.java:88) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.connection.ConnectionsJaxrsService.createConnection(ConnectionsJaxrsService.java:90) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.csrf.JSCsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(JSCsrfGuardFilter.java:72) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.csrf.CrossDomainCommunicationFilter.doFilter(CrossDomainCommunicationFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at com.jaspersoft.ji.jaxrs.diagnostic.DiagnosticLoggingFilterPRO.doFilter(DiagnosticLoggingFilterPRO.java:43) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:143) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.multipleTenancy.MTBasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(MTBasicProcessingFilter.java:194) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:235) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:43) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:235) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:57) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:80) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:43) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.encryption.EncryptionFilter.doFilter(EncryptionFilter.java:150) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at com.jaspersoft.ji.license.JILicenseFilter.doFilter(JILicenseFilter.java:86) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SessionDecoratorFilter.doFilter(SessionDecoratorFilter.java:63) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.httpheaders.ResourceHTTPHeadersFilter.doFilter(ResourceHTTPHeadersFilter.java:77) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:43) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2521) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2510) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Could not connect to buyeatest2sqldwserver.database.windows.net:1433: Connection reset at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:439) at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:351) at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:664) at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:587) at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:105) ... 134 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source) at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.packet.read.ReadPacketFetcher.getReusableBuffer(ReadPacketFetcher.java:83) at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.packet.read.ReadInitialConnectPacket.(ReadInitialConnectPacket.java:86) at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:399) ... 138 more

Comment: What drivers are you using? You post mention a MySQL driver and the error message a MariaDB driver.

Comment: Are you using a MariaDB driver for SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server to connect to a SQL Azure Database from Jasper Server. Please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-to-an-azure-sql-database) documentation.

Now [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-community-project-administrator-guide/v630/azure-sql-data) article of Jasper Soft is dedicated to Azure SQL Data Sources.

Hope this helps.